# Ribbon component for Adobe Flex or Aswing?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Anyone can point me to free or commercial Ribbon component done for Adobe Flex or Aswing? I seen one at some point but for some reason cant find any now. (Please don't mention minddomo, since it has nothing to do do with my question).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A Ribbon implementation in Flex would be a lot different from the standard TabNavigator. You must consider groups within each tab, and dynamic buttons within each group, and group popups etc.

I know this isn't an answer, but I don't know how to reply to the previous answer. :)

Comment: a bit offtopic, but still -- cristi, glad to see you around ;) You definitely should write ore in your description, man, so people will know what a great person they have here around ;)

Comment: There is a "add comment" link under the question.  If it does not show up you probably need a higher score.  As I understand it; a Ribbon changes the buttons (and other controls) based on context.  How would you expect a component to help you change the "Ribbon" based on context?  What APIs would you be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of one.  But, whenever anyone asks for one I ask this question:

What is the difference between a Ribbon and a TabNavigator with a button bar as the children?

I'd consider creating one for Flextras if anyone could explain what the difference was.

Comment: Why not pack TabNavigator, stick label "Ribbon" and sell it :)

Comment: Ribbons are a lot more than just a TabNavigator and a bunch of buttons. Microsoft published [some sort of guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872782.aspx) that describe what a Ribbon should/shouldn't do and how it should look like. AFAIK you have to get a [Office UI License](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx) too if you build your own Ribbon implementation.

Comment: Gerhard, i think you perfectly answered to Flextras, link to Microsoft guidelines is more than enough to explain anyone what is so different between ribbon and tab-navigator...